# How to save two separate plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

For my deep learning project I am trying to save the training accuracy and validation accuracy for each epoch as a graph, and similarly the training loss and the validation loss.

The first plot saves correctly but the second plot includes both the plots in the same gridlines (plot).

```py
"""#Plot Training & Test Accuracy"""

epochs_list = [i for i in range(epochs)]
plt.plot(epochs_list, acc, label='Training accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs_list, val_acc, label='Validation accuracy')
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig("V5_Full_Accuracy.png")

print("")



"""#Plot Training & Test Loss"""
plt.plot(epochs_list, loss, label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs_list, val_loss, label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
plt.savefig(V5_Full_Loss.png)
```

Comment: You need to plot your validation and training data in two different figures. See [Multiple Figs Demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html)

Comment: do a `plt.figure()` before second plot?

Comment: @QuangHoan, that works! Can't believe it was that simple! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @QuangHoang:

plt.figure() before second plot worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `plt.show()` **after** `plt.savefig()`.

```
plt.savefig("V5_Full_Accuracy.png")
plt.show()
```

Same for the second plot.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Second plot still combines the two graphs into one. So all 4 lines (Train Acc, Val Acc, Train Loss, Val Loss) show on the same grid.